# How to detect CSS property of an image using some tools

Tags: html, css, user-interface, adobe, ui-design

I am a UI developer. My question is suppose I have provided an image from client, now with this image is it possible to detect its CSS properties that is what is the font size used in a particular area, what is the color, width, margin, padding etc through some software or tools like adobe Photoshop etc.

If yes can I get some link or tutorials of how to do that .

Any help is appreciable .

Thanks !!!

Comment: If u open the image in chrome then there are many developer plugins for google chrome

Comment: What kind of image is it? A screenshot of an existing web page?

Comment: It can be any image like jpg, png etc

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to detect css properties in chrome right click on the element you wish to see the css properties of, then go to inspect, you will see all the css styles associated with that element on the right side of the developer tools window that opens. Personal tip, click the computer tab on the right of styles to get an easy overview of what is actually rendered.

for a tutorial check out https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: The OP wants to inspect images for font size etc. The chrome developer tools only allow you to inspect HTML web pages and not images.

Comment: ah, I miss understood the question due to the mention of css, if the OP wants to detect fonts in the image then try https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ I have had mixed results with it before, as for things like padding and margins, just use guides in photoshop or what ever your image editing software of choice is to get the measurements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Photoshop's ruler and guides (Gimp can also do that) to measure things like width and margin.

As for font size I would just create a text layer in Photoshop, position it above the text in the image and eyeball it for size.

EDIT: As requested here are a few useful links:

- [Official Photoshop Documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/measurement.html)
- [Photoshop Measure Tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpJ_X1cU-8Y)

Comment: Thanks for your response, do u have any tutorial or link , how to do that, because I dont know much about above tools , I never used that

Comment: I've added a few links in my answer that might be useful to you.